# Click an enter button to create a new textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

How do I create a new `TextBox` by clicking an enter button? And how do I focus the cursor on the new textbox (the cursor focus on the last textbox every time the new textbox has been created)?

I has been tried this code:

```
"private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Enter += new EventHandler(textBox1_Enter);
        }

        private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox tb = new TextBox();

            tb.Size = new Size(100, 50);
            tb.Location = new Point(100, 100);

            Controls.Add(tb);
        }"
```

But it not create a new textbox when i press an enter button

Comment: There are many ways to accomplish this. What have you got so far? Are you using code behind? MVVM? We need some help here.

Comment: hi @Kazuo: i haven't try yet, yet i'm confuse where do i have to start to create a new textbox when i clicked an enter button

Comment: hi @Kazuo: please refer to my question again. Thanks

Comment: have you looked at any of the answers posed below? Jonesy for example has a promising solution that could work for you if you provide him with more information about how you need it to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you load your form:

```
this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(Form1_KeyDown);
```

then

```
void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Return)
    {
        TextBox textbox = new TextBox();
        this.Controls.Add(textbox);
        textbox.Focus(); 
    }
}
```

Essentially, create the event that fires when a key is pressed.  If the key is the return key, create the textbox.

Your sample code doesn't really make sense because you are firing events from a textbox, when you want them fired from the form.

Comment: I can't really help more without you helping me

Answer (score 0):

```
        TextBox myTextBox=new TextBox();


        myTextBox.Visible=true;



        myTextBox.Left=100;
        myTextBox.Top=200;

        myTextBox.Text="ABC";
                    this.Controls.Add(myTextBox);
```

As for moving the cursor:

```
        this.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
        Cursor.Position = new   Point(this.Left+myTextBox.Left+50,this.Top+myTextBox.Top+50);
```