# A new window called twice after the mainForm, but first Form not being closed

Tags: c#, winforms

i have a problem:

Here is my case:

i already command a NewForm to be called everytime the user select that. The MainForm is being called when i run the program, and when i click "NewForm", the FirstNewForm being called and the MainForm is closed. But, when i click "NewForm" again in the FirstNewForm that i had created, it called the SecondNewForm, but the FirstNewForm is not being closed.

Here is my question:

How do i close the FirstNewForm? i mean, how do i close a CurrentForm whenever i called a NewForm?

Here is the image when i command a "NewForm" when the MainForm still in there, and MainForm is closed when FirstNewForm being called: (if you see in the taskbar, just one Selling System Program in there): (The first image is MainForm, and the second image is FirstNewForm, it looked the same, because the MainForm already closed when i called a FirstNewForm):

[image]

[image]

Here is the image when i command a "NewForm" when the FirstNewForm still in there, and FirstNewForm is not being closed when SecondNewForm being called: (if you see in the taskbar,there are two Selling System Programs in there, so the FirstNewForm is not being closed)

[image]

How do i hide and close the FirstNewForm?

Here is the code:

```
private void AddNewForm(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //this.Hide();
        Form newForm = new Form();
        AddObjects(sender, e, newForm);
        UpdateTextPosition(sender, e, newForm);

        newForm.Size = new Size(1360, 735);
        newForm.Text = "Selling System";
        newForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Fixed3D;
        newForm.AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Font;
        newForm.AutoScroll = true;
        newForm.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
        newForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        newForm.MaximizeBox = false;
        newForm.Controls.Add(label1);
        newForm.Controls.Add(label2);
        newForm.Controls.Add(label3);
        newForm.Controls.Add(label4);
        newForm.Controls.Add(label5);
        newForm.Controls.Add(label6);
        newForm.Controls.Add(label7);
        newForm.Controls.Add(menuStrip1);

        //newForm.ShowDialog();

        //this.Close();

        if(this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            Action act = () =>
            {
                this.Hide();
            };

          this.Invoke(act);
        }

        else
        {
          this.Hide();
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance! and sorry if i am post a long posting

Comment: You ask an awful lot of questions in a short period of time: 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18348480/text-not-all-displayed-by-the-time-new-form-has-been-created 2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18338451/click-an-enter-button-to-create-a-new-textbox 3. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18332405/create-a-new-form-every-time-a-button-has-been-clicked and now this one, can you at least try to figure it something on your own?

Comment: @MaxMommersteeg: well, i am sorry sir MaxMommersteeg, because i asked a lot of questions

Comment: @HabibZare: on my experience, Show() function is to appear the program just a seconds only, not permanent.. and i dont want that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ShowDialog` causes a modal dialog to show. This means, the call `newForm.ShowDialog()` will block and `this.Close()` will only be reached AFTER you close the new form. You could call `this.Hide()` on the main form to make it invisible and close all forms together when you exit your program:

```
this.Hide();

newForm.ShowDialog();

this.Close();
```

**EDIT**

It might appear that your call to `this.Hide()` is not properly dispatched to the UI-thread and so it refuses to hide the form. Try

```
if(this.InvokeRequired){
     Action act = () => {
          this.Hide();
     }
     this.Invoke(act)
}
else{
     this.Hide();
}
```

**'NOTHER EDIT**

```
private void AddNewForm(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...

    if(this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        Action act = () =>
        {
            this.Hide();
        };

      this.Invoke(act);
    }

    else
    {
      this.Hide();
    }

    newForm.ShowDialog();

}
```

Comment: He calls `this.Hide()` at the top of the method

Comment: we can use this.Close(); before newForm.ShowDialog();

Comment: No, you can't. If it is the main Window, you will terminate the process!

Comment: hello @bash.d: i already tried the above code, (while i create a NewForm in MainForm, the MainForm and the NewForm closed together, but the NewForm cannot be opened or the program direct close when i click a "New" to create a new form) Thanks

Comment: Please refer to my question code, i already update it @bash.d. Thanks

Comment: @bash.d: the firstnewform still on there when i called secondnewform. I have been tried "newForm.Hide(); and then newForm.ShowDialog(); and then newForm.Close();", but the firstnewform still on there when i called secondnewform. Thank you so much

Comment: @bash.d: i am sorry, what do you mean by proceed exactly like with the main window? i dont get it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35913/discussion-between-fuhans-and-bash-d)

Comment: No, I won't, sorry... Got other things to spend my time on.

Answer (score 0):

On the mainform You must assign to both childforms eventhandlers OnFormClosed.
There You can react properly  and control each child forms behaviour as it should be done.

Comment: i am sorry, i don't get what are you suggest to me. Sorry >.<